# Matrix computations problem: rank, pseudo inverse,...

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convex-optimization

Suppose we are given two arbitrary $m \times n$ matrices, $A$, $B$, where we know $B$ has full column rank. Let $m>>n$.
Can we always find a **square $m \times m $ matrix $X$**, such that $A=XB$?  I do not care if $X$ is unique or not, as long as one exists.

Comment: In optimization, can we optimize wrt $X$ instead of $A$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The rank of $B$ is $n$, so $B$ has a trivial nullspace. Take $X = AB^{+}$, where $B^{+}$ is the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse of $B$. Then
$$XB = AB^{+}B = AI_n = A.$$